# Blazor application crashing when trying to send request to another site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor app that will be opened via a parent site into a child window. I then want the Blazor app to Post information back to the parent site using this function:

```
    function OpenDocument(URL) {
        window.opener.postMessage(URL, "*");
        return false 

    }
```

This function is triggered by a switch case depending on what file the user clicks on. This is the switch statement code.

```
string res = "url string" ;
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("OpenDocument", Res);
```

This is the error message that I am getting in Chrome when the javascript function is triggered.

```
blazor.server.js:formatted:2869 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

I have looked around for information on this problem and can't seem to find much on it. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `res` and `Res` are different in case that is not a typo :)

Comment: @steve Greene I believe that was a typo when I formatted it on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a work around for anyone that might encounter this problem. Open a blank webpage with a url paramater as the message you want to post and have the blank web page post the message for you. If anyone has any better solutions please post them anyway.